# Multiplication of Infinity

Tags: calculus

Consider the following inequality with $f$ a real-valued continuously differentiable function and $\delta$ is a real non-negative number and a function of $x$.

$$1 \geq \delta f'(x).$$

Suppose $f'(x)$ converges to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to zero.

My intuition is that since the right-hand side is bounded by 1, $\delta$ should converge to $0$ as $x$ goes zero.

What is the best way to analytically show this?

Comment: Is $\delta$ a function of $x$?

Comment: What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: If $\delta >0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) = \infty$ then $\lim_{x\to 0} \delta f'(x) = \infty $. Now matter how close $\delta$ is to $0$ this will happen since you have stated $\delta$ is a fixed number. Take a very large $N>0$ such that $\delta > \frac{1}{N}$, then $\frac{1}{N}$ is very small. $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{N} f'(x) = \infty$ so it follows $\lim_{x\to 0} \delta f'(x) = \infty $.

Comment: @B.Martin It is a function of $x$.

Comment: @oliverjones Thanks, Oliver. delta is a function of $x$.

Comment: I see your edit, well then for $1 \ge \delta(x)f'(x)$ t to remain true for $x\to 0$ then yes need $\delta(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Moreover, need it to not converge "slower" to $0$ than $f'(x)$ converges to $\infty$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Is there any reason for the assumption that $f(x)$ is **continuously** differentiable, rather than simply (finitely) differentiable? Since no continuity assumptions are made regarding $\delta(x),$ I don't see how $f'(x)$ being continuous makes working with the product function $(f\delta)(x)$ more tractable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small enough $x$,  $f'(x) > 0$  (Since it goes to $ +\infty$). Hence we can rearrange the inequality

$$
\frac{1}{f'(x)} \ge \delta(x).
$$
Noting the $\delta(x) \ge 0$ we can then use the squeeze theorem to conclude that

$$\lim_{x \to 0 } \delta(x) = 0.$$